# Regex to match the argument of a function

Tags: regex

I need to match the argument of a function with a specific name. (In this case let's say the function name if `function`)

So basically if there is a occurrence like `function(my_argument)` in a file, I want to extract the argument `my_argument` from it. (basically what i need here is to collect all the argument passed to the `function()` in that file)

So far I came up with a regex

```
(([;][ ]{0,})|([ ]{1,})|(\n))function[(](([^()]*)*)[)]
```

But seems it does not catch it if the `function(my_argument)` is the first line of the file. [check example in regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2dGsfz/4).

Is there any way to capture that instance as well. Or if there are better ways to do this i'm open to suggestions as well, and highly appreciate it.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen `function(sin(theta)); function(5)` depending on implementation might get either `sin(theta` or `sin(theta)); function(5`

Comment: Try [`(^|;?[ ]+|\n)function[(]([^()]*)[)]`](https://regex101.com/r/sXelqd/1)

Comment: @JimD. yes. But let's assume in this case it won't be like that. Just simple function call in a line. No complex usage.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow. thanks it seems to do so. If you can give an explanation about how you come up with that it will be helpful for me and others as well. Please put it as an answer if you can but it is fine if you chose not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want

```
(^|;?[ ]+|\r?\n)function[(]([^()]*)[)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sXelqd/2)

**Details**:

- `(^|;?[ ]+|\r?\n)` - Group 1 capturing

  - `^` - start of string
  - `|` - or
  - `;?[ ]+` - an optional `;` followed with 1+ spaces
  - `|` - or
  - `\r?\n` -  a linebreak (an optional CR followed with LF)
- `function`  - a literal char sequence
- `[(]` - a literal `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `[)]`- a literal `)`.

Comment: yep. Might help some other also. Thank you.